# getHeader on ClientRequest in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Does `getHeader(name)` on the ClientRequest constructor function simply return the value of the header, or a more complex object? Can someone point me to reference documentation for this?

Comment: It's defined [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/2eddd7411234bf633df6a7bdb9c120ed89853324/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L346).

Comment: Make it an ans and I'll accept...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ClientRequest`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/2eddd7411234bf633df6a7bdb9c120ed89853324/lib/_http_client.js#L42) is based on `OutgoingMessage`, and its `getHeader` method is defined [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/2eddd7411234bf633df6a7bdb9c120ed89853324/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L346). The method returns a `String`.

Answer (score -1):

as robertklep mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530409/2842568 ClientRequest is based on OutgoingMessage, but if the _header[key] is string or not it isn't checked. You can simply set any value (any object for example) in [setHeader](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L325) method, and this value will be returned in getHeader method

Comment: This answer proposes a serious anti-pattern, which will obscure the intention of your code and make it less maintainable, since although the function returns a type ``<Any>`` headers passed in and out of the system will be serialised as strings.